# Add function to function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I suppose this is an easy problem to solve, it's just a little bit tricky to google. I have this function that random generates some numbers for 1 second until it reaches the real value (`number()`), just a flashy effect. However, the value is a 7 digit number and I want to separate it with commas. I have working functions for both of the functions but I dont know how to make them work together. I've tried to add the `digits()` function to my `number()` function but I cant get the commas to show while the number is random generating, only when it's done.

This is my `number()` code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        number: function(options) {
            if ( ! this.length)
                return false;

            this.defaults = {
                endAt: 90,
                numClass: 'autogen-num',
                interval: 65  // ms
            };
            var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);

            var $num = $('<span/>', {
                'class': settings.numClass
            });

            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                // Wrap each number in a tag.
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                    numLen = settings.endAt.toString().length;
                for (x = 0; x < numLen; x++) {
                    var rand_num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
                    frag.appendChild( $num.clone().text(rand_num)[0] )
                }
                $this.empty().append(frag);

                var get_next_num = function(num) {
                    ++num;
                    if (num > 9) return 0;
                    return num;
                };

                // Iterate each number.
                $this.find('.' + settings.numClass).each(function() {
                    var $num = $(this),
                        num = parseInt( $num.text() );

                    var interval = setInterval( function() {
                        num = get_next_num(num);
                        $num.text(num);
                    }, settings.interval);

                    setTimeout( function() {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }, settings.duration * 1000 - settings.interval);
                });

                setTimeout( function() {
                    $this.text( settings.endAt.toString() );
                }, settings.duration * 1000);
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And this is my `digits()` code:

```
$.fn.digits = function(){ 
    return this.each(function(){ 
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about setting up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for those two functions to show us how they are supposed to work.

Comment: @adeneo Sure, this is the number animation: http://jsfiddle.net/Cheezen/3pGpN/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers function replaces only one number at the time, and it relies on the numbers being numbers, so replacing them during the loop with a string containing commas is'nt really an option!

I rebuilt the numbers function to handle a string instead. No idea if it's what you're looking for, but it's the closest I could get:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.numAnim = function(options) {
        if (!this.length) return false;

        this.defaults = {
            endAt: 2060,
            numClass: 'autogen-num',
            duration: 1,   // seconds
            interval: 30  // ms
        };
        var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options),
            $this = this,
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                var numb = parseInt(Math.random() * (Math.pow(10, settings.endAt.toString().length)));
                $this.text(numb.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
            }, settings.interval),
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
                $this.text(settings.endAt.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
            }, 1000*settings.duration);
    }
})(jQuery);


$("#number").numAnim({
    endAt: 4103518,
    duration: 1
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XFF4M/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery, but id on't know by if you can put a callback anyehrere in there.  A callback is triggered when the after the function completed.

On the workaround side, you are saying, it generate a random number for 1 seconds, but you also say it has 7 digits. either way you will get he logic, and surely can make asjust it.

1. You make a boolean variable, and once your second (1000ms) is over OR your random number length get to 7, it switch the bool to true.
2. You later in your code, add a while loop, thet runs until that boolean is set to true and trigger you 2nd function from there.

i'm sure this is one of many ways to do this. Hope it helps. maybe someone has a better sugestion.
Chhers!